# FYI: Stepping out until 22nd

Tags: support, moderation

FYI: I'm on vacation until 22nd, trekking in the mountains, with no access to Internet.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. We'll keep an eye on things in your absence.

Comment: I'm back and catching up